# Get total frame count from MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there any way to get total frames in a video before actually playing the video using `MPMoviePlayerController`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty short and simple: no

Reasoning: `MPMoviePlayerController` plays all sorts of content. Among the vast range of content formats also is HTTP streaming. For a HTTP video stream it is impossible to get a deterministic frame count upfront as such value depends on the chosen bandwidth (chosen while being played).

You should clarify in your question on which content exactly you are trying to get this information; e.g. local video, streaming video, progressively downloaded video. Even though you will always be out of luck with streaming video, you might have a chance on the other two given options by using AVFoundation (did not actually verify this, I just know the information is available but I do not know off hand if the iOS SDK helps you gathering it).

Comment: I want Local video frames.. not a streaming Video frame.. Actually my requirement is that:  example. It displays the Duration "00:22:11:18" I want show that before playing the video..example.(Hours) (Minutes) (Seconds) (Frames) .. i got the Hours Minute and Seconds with below code...but i need frames ? how can i got it ?

Comment: -(NSString *)gettotladuration:(NSString *)url 
{   AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
CMTime duration = playerItem.duration;
float  seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
NSLog(@"duration: %0.2f", seconds);
int hours, minutes;
hours = seconds / 3600;
minutes = (seconds - (hours*3600)) / 60;
seconds = (int)seconds % 60;
NSString *time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes,(int)seconds];
return time;
}

Answer (score 0):

About as close as you can get using the high-level `MediaPlayer.framework` classes would be to check the movie player's `duration` property (if it's set) and multiply by the frame rate of the video. The next problem is finding the frame rate of the video..

Comment: duration can be available (unless its a live-stream) - but the framerate will vary, hence the frame count is not available (for HTTP streams).

Comment: Edited the relevant portion of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I want Local video frames.. not a streaming Video frame.. Actually my requirement is that:  example. It displays the Duration "00:22:11:18" I want show that before playing the video..example.(Hours) (Minutes) (Seconds) (Frames) .. i got the Hours Minute and Seconds with below code...but i need frames ? how can i got it ?

Comment: -(NSString *)gettotladuration:(NSString *)url 
{   AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
CMTime duration = playerItem.duration;
float  seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
NSLog(@"duration: %0.2f", seconds);
int hours, minutes;
hours = seconds / 3600;
minutes = (seconds - (hours*3600)) / 60;
seconds = (int)seconds % 60;
NSString *time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes,(int)seconds];
return time;
}

Comment: You can't, unless you make your own movie player using the `AVFoundation` framework, or perhaps even `CoreVideo`.